# How to retrieve items through table relationship when table ends in 's' (i.e. Wbs)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table called 'Wbs'. I've generate the controller which works fine when executing from the command line.

Example:

> Wbs
>
> Wbs(id: integer, description: string, project_id: integer, wbs_no: string, published: boolean, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime))

The problem is when I attempt to return all Wbs objects for a given project. Rails removes the 's' from wbs and tries to make a call to a method called "Project::Wb" instead of "Project::Wbs".

Example:

> Projects.first.wbs
>
> Project Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" LIMIT 1
> NameError: uninitialized constant Project::Wb

I do have belong_to and has_many set in their respective models.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should tell the Rails that your model name is not like it is expecting for. You could do so with:

```
has_many :wbs, :class_name => "Wbs"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify that "wbs" is *uncountable*. In `config/initalizers/inflections.rb` add:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable "wbs"
end
```

You'll have to restart your server / console afterwards.